# Explaining vector problem

Tags: mathematics, vector

I'm trying to simulate a centipede game, and I'm doing the snake movement. 
I have seen that piece of code, but can't get it, I know it gets the different between the current, previou's nodes positions, but what is the point of multiplying by the normal vector ?

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i < nodes.size(); i++ )
    {

    Vec2f diff =  nodes[i-1].m_Pos-nodes[i].m_Pos;

    float length = diff.length();
    Vec2f norm = diff.normalized();
    nodes[i].m_Pos+=(length - 5)*norm;

    }
```

Comment: The normal just gets the direction of the difference. Then it just moves each piece by (length-5) in that direction. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitVector.html

Comment: is there a better way for doing that ? moving the snake body according to the head?  the code actually is like a rope
Why the normal should be multiplied? it should be added to the position? not to scale the different by the normal ?

Comment: nodes[i].m_Pos+=(length - 5)*norm;
The normal is just the direction the next piece needs to move. The += means at that much to the position. So if head (piece 0) is at [20, 10], and next is at [10,10] (snake going right) then: diff is [10,0]; length is 10, and norm is [1,0]. It moves the piece (10-5)*[1,0] = [5,0] so, 5 pixels to the right.

Comment: you can put it as an answer :)

Comment: I tried to let the first node move and at the screen edge, I give it a negative velocity downwards with x = 0. The problem that the following nodes doesn't move accordingly, I don't know why ?

Comment: To tell you more, all other nodes always rotate and doesn't move vertically or horizontally, when the first nodes gets a negative velocity downwards or upwards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, a vector is said to be normal to a surface if it is perpendicular. In other words, normal vectors always point directly away from something.

Multiplying a scalar by a normal vector will get you a vector that represents displacement in the direction of the normal. Often normals have a handy property that they are unit-length, so if you want to move 5 units in the normal direction, nothing more than a multiplication is necessary. If it is not the case that the normal is unit-length, then an expensive normalization will be required.

Now, I am concerned by the naming in this code snippet. **Norm** actually has a *different* meaning from **normal**. In many contexts, the norm is actually the length, size or extent. A vector's norm, for instance, is a scalar that represents its length.

The fact that directly above the variable named `norm` is another variable named `length` and `norm` is declared as a vector rather than a scalar give enough context clues to indicate that `norm` is probably short-hand for normal, but this is poor naming.

Comment: Thanks, I have a problem right now. when the first node bounces and changes its velocity, the following nodes don't move at the way the first node moved.. the sample is here http://www.gamedev.net/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=17622

Comment: I would submit another question for this, there is not a lot I can do with an executable and no source code / problem description.